# Get list of purchased apps Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-services, google-play

I'm currently working on an app that lists all purchased apps (Like "Purchased Apps" in Google Play Store).
Is there a solution to get a list of app that contains in app billing ?
How can we know if an app has been purchased or not ?
Is a rooted phone needed for this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of installed applications supporting in-app billing, you can check for their permissions:

```
final List<PackageInfo> inAppBillingEnabledPackages = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<PackageInfo> installedAppInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
for (final PackageInfo packageInfo : installedAppInfo) {
    if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions != null) {
        for (final String permissionInfo : packageInfo.requestedPermissions) {
            if ("com.android.vending.BILLING".equals(permissionInfo)) {
                inAppBillingEnabledPackages.add(packageInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
// inAppBillingEnabledPackages now contains a list of packages supporting in-app billing
```

This works fine with a non-rooted phone.

As for "purchased apps", do you mean which installed apps have been paid for and are not free ? If so, for apps downloaded from Play, since I don't think the Play app supports any such Intent, I guess the only way would be to get the price of the app (which will depend on the country !) from an API like the ones listed in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557300/finding-a-list-of-all-the-android-apps-on-the-market), for example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-market-api/price/android-market-api/nDpJPGgWdSU/LJyPxxwT-KsJ)'s an example of how to get the price info in a given locale using [android-market-api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).

Comment: How does this app get the list of purchased apps of the user: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is not possible. What you can still try is to use standard [call to query all products](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) with an empty list of products. It works for application owning these products. I've never tried whether it works for any application, but you can give it a try.

```
// must be initialized first
IInAppBillingService service; 

// query products
Bundle skusBundle = new Bundle();
skusBundle.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", new ArrayList<String>());
Bundle response = service.getSkuDetails(3, "<package name>", "inapp", skusBundle);
```